# Need help checking my recurrence for a simple algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

All I'm writing to get a second opinion on the algorithm shown in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtfnV.jpg). I'm pretty sure its supposed to be $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n$ but I can't see where I'm supposed to get the +n from. So far I'm getting $T(n)=2T(n/2)+c$.

Can anyone help point out what I'm missing?

If I am right though wouldn't that mean that I can't use the masters method or the recursion tree for this problem?

Thanks